New to xlm blockchain
I hope this doesn’t sound like a stupid question but is it possible to build my Stellar dapp inside an iframe environment of another SaaS or in their marketplace?
Or more importantly could anyone help me with the basics of getting the dapp to have a frontend UI/UX. I have SaaS we can implement to.
I'm interested in only Stellar payment wallets and Soroban smart contracts.
